# Airflow job is started before scheduled time

Tags: airflow

I am confused by the behavior of Airflow scheduling. I have a daily job which should run at 11:59 CET. My understanding is that the job should be run at the end of the data interval which would be Dec 31st 11:59. But instead the job is run on Dec 31st 11:53.

Below is the DAG code. I am using Airflow 2.2.0.

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2018, 9, 24, 10, 00, 00,
                              tzinfo=pendulum.timezone('UTC')),
    'concurrency': 0,
    'retries': 0,
    'catchup': False,
}


with DAG('and_another_dag5',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval='59 11 * * *',
         #catchup=True,
         ) as dag:
    dummy = DummyOperator(task_id='run_ths')
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this behavior was caused by using MS SQL as the backend in Airflow v2.2.0. Switching back to Postgres solves the issue for us.

See also https://giters.com/apache/airflow/issues/19651.